# Swift-UITableView show swiped cells in editing style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am working on one tableview and I would like to make animation with defaultly enabled editing style, where all cells would be swiped to left and I would be able to see delete button in all cells and for example after 1 second, I want to go to default state of tableview. It's due to informing user, that some swipe feature is there available.
Has anyone any idea how to implement it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to show Delete Button in all cells at the same time ?

Comment: Yes. FYI i would like to do that for the first time, when the user show this view controller, where the tableview is. Few applications has this feature.